# How to change own password in a cascaded remote desktop session

Tags: remote-desktop, change-password

I log into COMPUTER1 with Windows remote desktop and inside this session I open a remote desktop session to COMPUTER2. All machines are Windows 10 or Windows Server 2016.

Now I want to change my password on COMPUTER2.

I know <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>END</kbd>, but this works only on COMPUTER1.

I tried `NET USER MyName * /DOMAIN`, which allows me to enter a password but then tells me that I have no access, probably because it thinks that I'm trying to modify someone else's password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of them propose the CTRL+ALT+END or the screen keyboard, which both did not work at least with my environment.

But it seems I overlooked [the petenetlive.com article](https://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0001183). The powershell script `(New-Object -COM Shell.Application).WindowsSecurity()` indeed did the job.

Also the "normal" commandline command `explorer.exe shell:::{2559a1f2-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}` seems to work.

Thanks to [Robert Harvey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102937/robert-harvey), for motivating me to do one more go... :-)

Comment: Excellent solution, I don't understand this hasn't got more upvotes...